# Finding the IV of AES CBC (CTF)

Tags: aes, cbc, initialization-vector

We have a python program that encrypts/decrypts plaintext given in hex to a cipher using AES CBC. We know that the IV is the same and is not going to change (it is stored in a file). How can we possibly find the IV, if found this will be the flag.

Comment: Hint: removed the first block, and see the new equations of decryption from the oracle and actual one!

Comment: The first block of what?

Comment: If I wrote a little longer that will make a problem for the CTF? If not I'll extend it!

Comment: It will not create a problem, It just for me the know how this is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request decryption for three blocks ( 2 is enough);

\begin{align}
P_1 =& Dec_k(C_0) \oplus IV\\
P_2 =& Dec_k(C_1) \oplus C_{0}\\
P_3 =& Dec_k(C_2) \oplus C_{1}\\
\end{align}

Now remove the first ciphertext, and request decryption;

\begin{align}
P'_2 =& Dec_k(C_1) \oplus IV\\
P_3 =& Dec_k(C_2) \oplus C_{1}\\
\end{align}

Now use the equations of $P_2$ and $P'_2$

$$\begin{align}
P_2 \oplus P'_2 &= Dec_k(C_1) \oplus C_{0} \oplus Dec_k(C_1) \oplus IV\\
& = C_{0} \oplus IV \\
P_2 \oplus P'_2 \oplus  C_{0} &= IV \\
\end{align}$$

---

In programmer aspect

```
defn CBCDecryptionOracle(c[]):
   return Dec(c[])

c = (c0,c1)

(p1,p2) = CBCDecryptionOracle(c)


p2' = CBCDecryptionOracle(c1)

print( p2 ^ p2' ^ c[0])
```

Note: you may need to find the size of c1 (that means the size of the block used in AES-CBC mode).

Comment: I'm a programmer not a mathematician ;) Could you provide this with an example please?

Comment: Request 2 decryption of two blocks then you have $P_1,P_2,C_1,C_2$ in your hands but the IV is missing. Now remove the first ciphertext and request decryption then you have a new $P'_2$ which is different. Now use what you have in your hand $P_2\oplus P'_2 \oplus C_0$  to obtain the IV.

Comment: Given the following:
P1 = FooBar (46 6f 6f 42 61 72)
C1 = 86c865a3b6fc2e5e7b8423e8ec7f48f3 

P2 = JohnDoe (4a 6f 68 6e 44 6f 65)
C2 = 338bcd8c0465d066843a6a7dc10abac6 

P3 = AliceBob (41 6c 69 63 65 42 6f 62)
C3 = f8cbf44f53a6b362cf683324eb2bd44a

Comment: You should encrypt a message that must have longer than 1 block of the AES so that you can use the proposed method.